# Can I switch to the Imperials after I join the Stormcloaks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Well, I don't know if this is even fixable. At the start of the game, I ended up joining the Imperials like I do any other time, but I accidentally joined the Stormcloaks by giving the Jagged Crown to Assface over in Windhelm.

My controller has always had issues with lag for odd reasons and often selects things I don't want it too. So, my question is: Am I stuck with this guy for the rest of the game? Is there a way to go back to the Imperials? I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: Could you not just load an earlier save? Autosave, or manual?

Comment: It happened at the start of the game. Unfortunately I'm not willing to give up 100+ hours and a daedric bow u~u;;

Comment: DO another Jagged Crown quest and give it back to tullius instead of Racist Ulfric!

Answer (score 1):

The UESP have a [handy graph](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Civil_War) on how the civil war can develop. Unfortunately, it seem that you are stuck with the Stormcloaks until the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. But you could always just start a new character, lel. Just boost your smithing so you can have Daedric Smithing again. Also, there's a very good tutorial that'll get you to to about Level 17 before leaving Helgen, if that would help. Sorry I couldn't provide any real assistance.